# How to Transform a Spark Scala Nested Map within a Map Data Structure?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to write a nested data structure consisting of a Map inside another Map using an array of a Scala case class.

The result should transform this dataframe:

```
|Value|Country| Timestamp| Sum|
+-----+-------+----------+----+
|  123|    ITA|1475600500|18.0|
|  123|    ITA|1475600516|19.0|
+-----+-------+----------+----+
```

into:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
[{"value":123,"attributes":{"ITA":{"1475600500":18,"1475600516":19}}}]
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The `actualResult` dataset below gets me close but the structure isn't quite the same as my expected dataframe.

```scala
case class Record(value: Integer, attributes: Map[String, Map[String, BigDecimal]])
val actualResult = df
  .map(r =>
    Array(
      Record(
        r.getAs[Int]("Value"),
        Map(
          r.getAs[String]("Country") ->
            Map(
              r.getAs[String]("Timestamp") -> new BigDecimal(
                r.getAs[Double]("Sum").toString
              )
            )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

The `Timestamp` column in the `actualResult` dataset doesn't get combined together into the same `Record` row but rather creates two separate rows instead.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|value                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------+
[{"value":123,"attributes":{"ITA":{"1475600516":19}}}]
[{"value":123,"attributes":{"ITA":{"1475600500":18}}}]
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of `groupBy` and `collect_list` by creatng combined column using struct  I was able to get single row as below output.

```
val mycsv =
    """
      |Value|Country|Timestamp|Sum
      |  123|ITA|1475600500|18.0
      |  123|ITA|1475600516|19.0
    """.stripMargin('|').lines.toList.toDS()


  val df: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", true)
    .option("sep", "|")
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .csv(mycsv)
  df.show

  val df1 = df.
    groupBy("Value","Country")
    .agg(  collect_list(struct(col("Country"), col("Timestamp"), col("Sum"))).alias("attributes")).drop("Country")


  val json = df1.toJSON // you can save in to file
  json.show(false)
```

Result combined 2 rows

```
+-----+-------+----------+----+
|Value|Country| Timestamp| Sum|
+-----+-------+----------+----+
|123.0|ITA    |1475600500|18.0|
|123.0|ITA    |1475600516|19.0|
+-----+-------+----------+----+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Value":123.0,"attributes":[{"Country":"ITA","Timestamp":1475600500,"Sum":18.0},{"Country":"ITA","Timestamp":1475600516,"Sum":19.0}]}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: updated my answer and Some how column labels are coming in side the json is it okay for you ?

Comment: can you check the result pls

Comment: Hi Eric,  let me know your feed back on this. if any questions please ask.